# Formatting String from Data

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have data like this:

```
Name    Update
CC      12/31/2012
CS      12/31/2012
CI      04/30/2013
CR      04/30/2013
```

I need this output:

```
Annual CC/CS Update: 12/31/2012
Annual CI/CR Update: 04/30/2013
```

If my data is like this, however:

```
Name    Update
CC      12/31/2012
CI      04/30/2013
```

I need this output:

```
Annual CC Update: 12/31/2012
Annual CI Update: 04/30/2013
```

Not sure how to accomplish this task.

**BTW, using Razor in ASP.Net MVC3**

Trying this: (Note AllianceDesignations is defined Designation[])

```
<div class="span6">
    @AllianceDesignations.GroupBy(x => x.UpdateDue).Select(g => String.Format("<p>Annual {0} Update: {1}</p>", String.Join("/", g.Select(y => y.Name).ToArray()), g.Key))
</div>
```

Shows this:

```
<div class="span6">
    System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.DateTime,MVC3MyPage.MyPageService.Designation],System.String]
</div>
```

Also, I am already putting them in a Dictionary for another use like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Designation> Designations = new Dictionary<string, Designation>();
```

Comment: can't post code in comments. but what I have doesn't look right.

Comment: Don't post in comments - edit the question.

Comment: What format is your data in? A CSV? A database? Flat strings in a file? A textarea?

Comment: The AllianceDesignations field is returned from my webservice as an array of Designation. Designation has fields Designated(int), Name(string), and UpdateDue(dateTime).

Comment: @MB34 Alright, now that I know what the data structure actually is, my technique should return a list of strings in the format you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var designationsByDate = allianceDesignations.GroupBy(designation => designation.UpdateDue).OrderBy(values => values.Key);
string[] rowsOfData = designationsByDate.Select(designationByDate => {
    string annual = designationByDate.Aggregate(string.Empty, (acc, designation) => acc + "/" + designation.Name);
    return string.Format("Annual {0} Update {1}", annual, designationByDate.Key);
}).ToArray();
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'.

Comment: @MB34 sorry, I forgot the .ToArray(); at the end, fixed.

Comment: I just made rowsOfData IEnumerable<string>. Now how can I strip out the Time portion of the DateTime value in the Designation? Each time I try to use a format on the value, I get an Explicit Conversion error.

Comment: And what if the UpdateDue is null? It actually is DateTime? nullable.

Comment: just change the `designationByDate.Key` to `designationByDate.Key.ToShortDateString()`

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage LINQ's [GroupBy extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx). Once you have retrieved your records (let's assume your class is Record), you can query your results the LINQ extensions. The code might not be perfect but it should give you the right idea.

```
IEnumerable<Record> records = ....
var groups = records.GroupBy( f => f.Update );

foreach( IEnumerable<Record> r in groups ){
  Write( String.Join( "/", r.Select( rec => rec.Name ).ToArray() ), r.First().Update ) );
}
```

Comment: @MB34: You don't need to be using a database to use LINQ.

Comment: In trying this, I get error "Cannot use local variable r before it is declared" at r.Select

Comment: As mentioned, the code isn't meant to be copied and pasted as a working solution but rather as a means of conveying the idea for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

First [group by](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) `Update`, then [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) the names in each group (untested):

```
data.GroupBy(x => x.Update)
    .Select(g => String.Format("Annual {0} Update: {1}", String.Join("/", g.Select(y => y.Name).ToArray()), g.Key)
```

Comment: Check out new data in original question.

Answer (score 0):

If your data source is SQL, you might try a query like this:

```
select Update , Name
from my_table
order by Update , Name
```

Now your data is properly ordered. You can read it and group it thusly, without linq, like so:

```
using ( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection( "some connect string" ) )
using ( SqlCommand    cmd  = conn.CreateCommand() )
{
  cmd.CommandText = @"select Update , Name from my_table order by Update , Name" ;
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text ;

  using ( SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
  {
    DateTime     prev_update = DateTime.MinValue ;
    List<string> names       = new List() ;
    while ( reader.Read() )
    {
      DateTime update = reader.GetDateTime( 0 ) ;
      String   name   = reader.GetString(   1 ) ;

      if ( update != prev_update )
      {
        if ( name.Length > 0 )
        {
          Console.WriteLine( "Annual {0} Update: {1}" , string.Join( "/" , names ) , prev_update ) ;
        }
        names.Clear() ;
        prev_update = update ;
      }

      names.Add( name ) ;

    }
    reader.Close() ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're reading from a file or not and a little unclear on the exact format but here is some code to do exactly what you want when reading from a plain text file with the format you specified.

```
//used to store converted data
Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

//open file, read line by line and store values as needed
using (TextReader tr = File.OpenText("test.txt"))
{
    //throw away header line
    string line = tr.ReadLine();
    while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] values = line.Split((char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (data.ContainsKey(values[1]))
            data[values[1]] += "/" + values[0];
        else
            data.Add(values[1], values[0]);
    }
}

//print results
foreach (string date in data.Keys)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Annual {0} Update: {1}", data[date], date));
```

Input:

```
Name    Update
CS      12/31/12
CI      12/31/12
CL      01/16/13
CS      01/16/13
```

Output:

```
Annual CS/CI Update: 12/31/12
Annual CL/CS Update: 01/16/13
```